# Selection area when capturing an image in android

Tags: android

I wanted to know if it is possible to select an area of an image(height and width) being previewed to save the image. I want this for optical character recognition.
Like Zxing app where user can select an area which is to be read, Zxing can actually select a part and then get the details.
The user can select an area by enlarging or reducing the rectangle and save that image.
Any code examples would be helpful.

Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.